# stop IPTABLES from prerouting to local IPs

Tags: debian, iptables, proxmox

I'm running a proxmox server and I'm redirecting ports to internal virtual machines via IPTABLES.

I'm following instructions here http://www.ameir.net/blog/archives/55-Running-Proxmox-behind-a-single-IP-address.html

```
-A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.100:22
-A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2223 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.101:22
-A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2224 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.104:22
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.4.0/24 -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I tried setting up port 80 on the host ip to redirect to a virtual machine and it caused all my virtualmachines port 80 to also be redirected.

Is there a way I can preroute and have it ignore any 192.x.x.x address'?

Comment: I read "port 80" in the text but "port 22" in the code. What are the available interface names and their IP addresses? What is the target address for connections to the public IP address?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want traffic to the host IP to get NATed somewhere else, it should help to specify the host IP with the `-d` option in your iptables rule:

```
-A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp -d $HOSTIP --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.100:22
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ACCEPT` target is the equivalent of `IGNORE` in NAT rules.  So to exempt `192.168.0.0/16` (I'm assuming you don't really mean `192.0.0.0/8`) addresses from any NAT you could say

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
```

Note that this will exempt those addresses from **all** NAT rules that follow in the `PREROUTING` chain.